# How to trigger a UiPath's automation via an HTTP request and display the extracted results via the robot in the JSON response?

Tags: uipath, uipath-robot, uipath-orchestrator, uipath-activity, uipath-api

I have built a UiPath's workflow/automation which extracts specific fields of a pdf. I wish to deploy it to a server and trigger that UiPath's job/automation via an HTTP request and deliver the extracted fields of a pdf in JSON format. The web application would also ask user to upload the pdf which would be saved to a path in the cloud server's storage. That path would be saved in UiPath's robot from where it would process the files.

Can you give me the steps and guide. Many thanks in advance.